# Creating sql procedure with insert,Update,delete and select operation in one procedure.Is this better way?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am use SQL Server 2008 R2 version.
I created procedure which includes all operation of table like select,insert, update,delete operation in one procedure.
Here is procedure i created.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[My_proc]    

    @Operation     nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

if(@Operation ='Insert')
Begin
--Insert query
End

if(@Operation ='Update')
Begin
--Update query
End

if(@Operation ='Delete')
Begin
--Delete query
End

if(@Operation ='Select')
Begin
--Select query
End

END
```

**which is better?

like above procedure example.

or
write separate query for each operation.**

Comment: yuk. Create a separate procedure for each operation. Though you can often combine the insert and update queries into a single proc.

Comment: I would use separate procedures for each, but would not put the SELECT in a procedure because it makes it harder to sort and filter on from a client